# TabHost displays content once (onCreate)

Tags: java, android, fragment, navigation-drawer, android-tabhost

I have a `TabHost` Inside a `navigationDrawer` and I'm facing this weird problem which occurs when ever i go from `TabHost` which exist as a navigation drawer item to another navigation drawer item and get back to `TabHost` it won't display its content, the first time it works perfectly but when ever I change the item and get back to it, it won't display the content; in other word it won't load child fragments, unless i closed the app and relaunch it or change the orientation (recreate fragment).

**How it looks first time i open it (with content)**

[image]

**After going to another navDrawer Item and return to TabHost**

[image]

**TabHost Fragment:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import info.fds.Emirates.R;

public  class MyFragment extends Fragment
{

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    public MyFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle instance)
    {
        super.onCreate(instance);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mTabHost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getActivity(), mTabHost, mViewPager);



        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Here we load the content for each tab.
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Incident").setIndicator("Incident"), PageOneFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Service Request").setIndicator("Service Request"), PageTwoFragment.class, null);
    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
    {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final TabHost mTabHost;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo
        {
            private final String tag;
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args)
            {
                tag = _tag;
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory
        {
            private final Context mContext;

            public DummyTabFactory(Context context)
            {
                mContext = context;
            }

            public View createTabContent(String tag)
            {
                View v = new View(mContext);
                v.setMinimumWidth(0);
                v.setMinimumHeight(0);
                return v;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager)
        {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mViewPager = pager;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
        {
            tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
            String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);

            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);

        }

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
        {
            int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
            // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
            // The jerk.
            // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
            // ViewPager.
            TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
            int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**PageOneFragment**:

```
public class PageOneFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pageone_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**PageTwoFragment**

```
public class PageTwoFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagetwo_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**Note:** After debugging i notice that `onCreateView()` in **PageOneFragment** and **PageTwoFragment** is not executed.

so what is happening and why the `tabHost` doesn't load its content after navigating to another item?

**EDIT:**
After hours of painful debugging, I found that my code never execute the fallowing method on the second call which is:

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)//never get executed after the second call
        {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);

            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);

        }
```

how could i solve this?

any help is truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post your entire code, just the necessary to understand your problem. It would be great if you could create a fiddle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this one ridiculous mistake cost me a lot of time, while the solution was actually very simple, the thing is that I was using  `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` after replacing it, everything work perfectly, hope this will help others with similar problem.

Comment: me faced exactly the same situation just two days back! for me also it took lot of time!! two days before only figured out this solution on a another SO post! yups it is ridiculous! (and this was my question! http://stackoverflow.com/q/30885610/2811343)

Answer (score 1):

In you code, the `FragmentPageAdapter` will using the activity's `FragmentManager` but when `instantiateItem` in `FragmentPageAdapter`, it will find the Fragment in activity's `FragmentManager`. It's unfortunate, the `PageOneFragment` and the `PageTwoFragment` has being in the activity's `FragmentManager`, so there are not  new creating `PageOneFragment` and `PageTwoFragment`, the `FragmentPageAdapter` will use the `PageOneFragment` in the Fragment backstack. But the `PageOneFragment` is added in the last `FragmentPageAdapter`, and then there are no content.

Using FragmentPageStateAdapter to replace FragmentPageAdapter is a simple choice. If you want to use `FragmentPageAdapter` that is better than `FragmentPageStateAdapter` at some times, you can use it like this:

```
    public TabsAdapter(Fragment fragment, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager)
    {
        super(fragment.getChildFragmentManager());


        mContext = fragment.getActivity();
        mTabHost = tabHost;
        mViewPager = pager;
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        Log.i("Test", "TabsAdapter super");
    }
```

using the `ChildFragmentManager`.

I think if you remove the `PageOneFragment` and `PageTwoFragment` in activity's `FragmentManager`, it is also ok.